# SSH- Starting an application on client instead of server

Tags: firefox, ssh

I am facing a weird problem. When I log on using ssh to my server start firefox there, ideally it should start firefox on that machine. However, it is starting firefox on my machine and not the cliet. Why this is happening?
I am logging in to the server with
`ssh -X username@ip`
after this just `firefox`

Comment: Can you please add the commands you are using and how exactly you are connecting via ssh to the target machine?

Comment: Updated now the ssh line

Comment: @user997704 can you tell us if you face this if client's Firefox is not running?

Answer (score 0):

With the `-X` flag you are enabling X11 forwarding. That means when the ssh server is configured the same...

```
# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

...you are forwading the window from the target machine to your local machine. So firefox IS started on the target machine, BUT it is displayed on your local machine.

Comment: I saw similar problem on my friends laptop. It only happens if clients Firefox is running otherwise the Firefox starts from server as usual. Can you help it now?

Answer (score 0):

When `firefox` starts (on the remote system), it wants to use the X server to display itself. It finds the X server to use through the DISPLAY variable in it's environment. By using the `-X` option on your `ssh` command, you're telling `ssh` to set the DISPLAY variable in your remote session to forward the X connection back to your local X server ("forward ...back?), so the `firefox` on the remote system displays on your local system.

To verify, execute `pgrep firefox` on each system, or even `pkill -9 firefox`.